# What's the point of @Before and @BeforeClass?

Tags: java, junit

Instead of using these JUnit 4 annotations, why don't we just use static and instance initializer blocks? The following code shows that a @BeforeClass method runs whenever a static initializer block runs, and a @Before methods runs whenever an instance initializer block runs. So why do we need them?

```
public class DemoTest {

    static {
        System.out.println("init static");
    }

    {
        System.out.println("init instance");
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpAll() {
        System.out.println("beforeClass");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        System.out.println("before");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("test1");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("test2");
    }
}
```

Comment: "@Before methods runs whenever an instance initializer block runs" - but not the other way around.

Comment: I wouldn't trust the the current test engine really creates a new instance for each test. So when the tests fail you have to debug the test engine and I don't think you want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are of course free to use those if your test cases do not require the additional functionality provided by `@Before`, etc.

Since you *can't* do the same thing as `@After` and `@AfterClass` with these constructs however, it makes sense for symmetry, reusability and readability to include them in the same format.

Additionally, for things like `@Rule` and `@ClassRule` annotated fields (as well as `@Mock` annotated if you're using `MockitoJUnit4Runner` or `@Autowired` if you're using `SpringJUnitRunner`), these are guaranteed to have been initialised by the time you enter the appropriate `@Before`, etc. method in JUnit.  There's no such guarantee (in fact, there's a guarantee that they *won't* have been) if you're using static/instance initialiser blocks.

Comment: Both runners you've mentioned also have respective rules that allow you to use library features without having to use the runner itself - you can have as many rules as you want (and at whatever scope you want), but you can only have a single runner, ever.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost to enable *declarative* programming; using annotations is just "how you do things" in JUnit, so it makes sense to use these constructs here, too.

And note: this is also for symmetry. You have `@After` and `@AfterClass` which you really couldn't express using (static) code blocks within the class!

Answer (score 1):

> @BeforeClass method runs whenever a static initializer block runs

The important caveat here is that this statement is wrong. Static initializer block runs **when the class is loaded**, which is not necessarily when you are meant to execute the tests.

Moving `@BeforeClass` into static-init block means it is invoked only once per classload, meaning you can no longer execute your test multiple times without reloading the class first (which is a tricky thing to do).

It is important to also note that `@BeforeClass` are not meant to prepare your test class for use - they are meant to prepare the *rest of your system* for running tests - and, for that reason, usually every `@BeforeClass` and `@Before` needs to be complemented with an appropriate `@AfterClass` and `@After` respectively, so that after all tests run, the system is cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the [junit 4 javadocs](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/index.html);
the reasoning behind each annotation is included in the description of the annotation.

Straight out of the JUnit JavaDocs:

For `@Before`

> When writing tests, it is common to find that several tests need similar objects created before they can run. Annotating a public void method with @Before causes that method to be run before the Test method. The @Before methods of superclasses will be run before those of the current class, unless they are overridden in the current class. No other ordering is defined.

For `@BeforeClass`

> Sometimes several tests need to share computationally expensive setup (like logging into a database). While this can compromise the independence of tests, sometimes it is a necessary optimization. Annotating a public static void no-arg method with @BeforeClass causes it to be run once before any of the test methods in the class. The @BeforeClass methods of superclasses will be run before those of the current class, unless they are shadowed in the current class.

Comment: Thanks but I don't see how this answers my question. The alternatives that I mentioned in the question (initializer blocks) also do what the Javadoc describes. But never mind, I'm happy with the other answers.